# Return QJSValue from C++ to qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have the following function that returns a javascript array as a QJSValue. But when I call this function from QML, the resulting object is always "undefined".

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY (QJSValue test READ test NOTIFY testChanged)

public:
    MyClass() {}

    QJSValue test()
    {
        QJSEngine engine;
        QJSValue l = engine.newArray(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            l.setProperty(i, i);
        }

        return l;
    }

    static void RegisterTypes()
    {
        qmlRegisterUncreatableType<MyClass>("MyTypes", 1, 0, "MyClass", "Creation of MyClass type not supported");
    }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void testChanged();

}

int main() {
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    MyClass mc;
    MyClass::RegisterTypes();
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myClass", &mc);

    // ...
}
```

This is almost exactly the way that it is recommended to work with arrays in the [Qt Docs on QJSValue](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsvalue.html#working-with-arrays).

The following button for example always outputs "undefined":

```
Button {
    onClicked: console.log(myClass.test)
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you add `QML_ELEMENT` as shown in this example https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-integrating-with-js-values-from-cpp.html ? Could you share the code that registers the C++ class?

Comment: @iam_peter I believe that the QML_ELEMENT macro should not be added to this class as I don't want `MyClass` to be instantiable from QML. It exists on the C++ side and then is exposed to QML through `engine.setContextProperty(...);`. I have added additional information.

Comment: @iam_peter Although I have tried it with QML_ELEMENT as well and it does not change the behavior.

Comment: Have you verified that code otherwise works, for example using same code except QString instead of QJSValue? Have you verified that test() returns a valid QJSValue (with debugger breakpoint or debug print in that method)?

Comment: @hyde Yes, for example `return QJSValue(5)` works perfectly. The problem always seems to be with arrays. For example, `return engine.evaluate("[1, 2, 3]");` also gives undefined. As far as "Verifying that it's a valid QJSValue", the debugger doesn't reveal any useful information, but `l.isArray()` returns true and `engine.hasError()` returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part to answer your question is written in this [paragraph](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-integrating-with-js-values-from-cpp.html#primitive-and-managed-values). Arrays are stored on the heap of the engine they were created with. In your case you have two separate engines. The one that comes from `QQmlApplicationEngine` and the other one that you create in the `test()` function. Both have a heap and are separate from one another, this is why the array is undefined. Primitives aren't stored on the heap that is why `return QJSValue(5)` works in your example.

To solve the issue you could forward the "main" engine to your `MyClass` and use it to create the array.

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

MyClass mc(&engine);
MyClass::registerTypes();
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myClass", &mc);
```

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QJSValue test READ test NOTIFY testChanged)

public:
    MyClass(QQmlEngine *engine)
        : m_engine(engine)
    {}

    QJSValue test()
    {
        QJSValue l = m_engine->newArray(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            l.setProperty(i, i);
        }

        return l;
    }

    static void registerTypes()
    {
        qmlRegisterUncreatableType<MyClass>("MyTypes",
                                            1,
                                            0,
                                            "MyClass",
                                            "Creation of MyClass type not supported");
    }

signals:
    void testChanged();

private:
    QQmlEngine *m_engine = nullptr;
};
```

[Here](https://github.com/iam-peter/stackoverflow/tree/main/questions/77687596) you can find the fully working example.